# How to create three private vlans using Netgear GS116Ev2

Tags: vlan, netgear

I'm trying to create two or more VLAN's on the Netgear GS116Ev2 switch where each VLAN shares a single port to access the Xfinity router for the internet but cannot communicate with other VLAN's.  Btw the router does not appear to support VLAN's.  I know there are a lot of answers but non which seem to explicitly answer this scenario.  I'm starting to think the router must support VLAN configurations.  Nevertheless, the goal is to isolate DATA, VOIP, iSCSI and perhaps a guest Wi-Fi subnet but for simplicity I'm starting with two VLAN's.

Here's what I have tried thus far for VLAN port:
VLAN 1: 1U, 2T (PVID 2), 3T (PVID 3)
VLAN 2: 2T, 4U, 5U, ..., 12U
VLAN 3: 3T, 13U, 14U, 15U, 16U

Comment: You are right, the router must support VLANs also, or it can't indicate to the switch (via 802.1q tagging) which VLAN a packet is intended for.

Comment: Thanks @MadHatter, I was afraid of that and explains a lot.  Do you know if a server has two nic's where one is on data vlan and the other on iscsi vlan does the server need to modify its routes saying the internet is on a the data vlan nic?  Btw, is it common to isolate iscsi traffic?

Comment: I would imagine it does, yes.  And I believe it is normal to isolate iSCSI traffic also.