# VLANs with gs116ev2 and not-VLAN-aware router

Tags: networking

I am trying to create a network like this:

- Router 192.168.0.1. not VLAN aware
- Switch gs116ev2
- Computers, some in 192.168.0.0, some in 10.1.1.0

Is it possible to configure gs116ev2 to provide this? I have tried Port-based VLANS, and have ports 1 to 8 on VLAN1 and 9 to 16 on VLAN2. Port 8 and 16 are connected to the router. However, machines on 10.1.1.0 LAN can see themselves but don't seem to get routed to the Internet. I was expecting the port 16 that goes to the router to be enough.

I have checked [How to create three private vlans using Netgear GS116Ev2](https://serverfault.com/questions/767481/how-to-create-three-private-vlans-using-netgear-gs116ev2) where 802.1Q is mentioned, so I am wondering if it could work via "Port based" instead.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the router configuration.  Does the router port on sw port 16 have an IP address in the 10.1.1.0 network?  Is that address the default gateway for those devices?

Comment: Not really, the router Web interface does not allow to edit any addresses except for the router address itself. This was my doubt too, whereas having one of the ports receiving packets from 10... if the router would redirect them

Comment: Sadly, based on your description, your router will not support multiple interfaces.  You'll need a commercial-class router to do this.